# Determine whether x(n) converges

Tags: real-analysis

This is just a simple exercise that I am struggling with.

Let $x(1):= a>0$, and $x(n+1) = x(n) + \frac1{x(n)}$

Determine whether the series converges or diverges. Now I have shown that the series is increasing using induction. Using random values of a and a calculator I am fairly sure that the series diverges. Any hints on how to go about doing this? I would assume that I start by assuming an < M for some M and find a contradiction, but I have no idea as to how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hand wavey approach: Suppose the sequence $x_n$ does converge some to some limit, say $\ell$, as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Taking the limit of both sides of the recurrence relation $x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{1}{x_n}$, we get

$$\ell=\ell+\frac{1}{\ell}\iff0=\frac{1}{\ell}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Outline:** It is easy to see that $x_2\gt 1$. Suppose that the sequence is bounded above. Let $M$ be the least upper bound. Then $M\gt 1$.

Because $M$ is the least upper bound of the $x_n$, there is an $n$ such that $x_n \gt M-\frac{1}{2M}$. From this we can conclude that $x_{n+1}\gt M$, and we have reached a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have $x(n) = a$ for some fitting $n, a$. Then I claim that $x(n + 2\lceil a\rceil ^2) \geq 2a$. If we assume otherwise, for contradiction, then to get from $x(n)$ to $x(n + 2\lceil a\rceil^2)$ we've added $2\lceil a\rceil^2$ terms, all greater than $\frac{1}{2a}$. But then we have
$$x(n + 2\lceil a\rceil ^2) \geq x(n) + 2\lceil a\rceil^2\cdot \frac{1}{2a} \geq a + \frac{2a^2}{2a} = 2a
$$